# jQuery $.ajax is not doing anything

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a jQuery AJAX request that does not seem to be doing anything.

I see no action on the Network tab on Chrome Debugger,

The error/success callbacks are not being called inside the function and nothing seem to happen on the server side whatsoever.

The thing is, this is not happening on my main local domain: http://dev.sitename.com

It only happen on my inner pages, for example: http://dev.sitename.com/about

My guess is there is some .htaccess rule that is damaging the process but I see no Network activity what so ever, so how could it be?

Here's my code:

```
$.ajax({
    url: 'ajax.php?cachekiller=' + (new Date()).getTime(),
    data: {
        action: 'doLogin'
    },
    success: function() {
    // Not being called
    },
    error: function() {
    // Not being called either
    }
});
```

Thank you

Comment: .htaccess could not prevent your browser from trying to hit the server. - you'd see SOMETHING in the network tab once the ajax calls goes out

Comment: check your console to see if there are any errors

Comment: Is your console showing any errors?

Comment: Placed it in a document. ready ?

Comment: is the code executing? do you see any error in the console?

Comment: no need for a document.ready theoretically unless you're appending sent data to the dom or doing some dom manipualtions.

Comment: Have you tried using type:'GET' with your Ajax Request

Comment: @sushanth ajax defaults to get.

Comment: Is there a JS error that stops the code running at all? Check the console as already suggested. If you replace the whole contents of the `success` and `error` function bodies with just `alert('test')` does that work? As an aside, why not just use jQuery's `cache:false` option rather than setting your own `cachekiller`?

Comment: can you try to trace any n/w movements using fiddler??

Comment: may be this is stupid,but is it reaching till that point? can you put two alerts before and after and check?

Comment: My console is not indicating any errors, and I debugged the JS and made sure it's going to that point - it does go there. but still, nothing goes to the server, no callback is called :-(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try putting cachekiller on data param

```
$.ajax({
    url: 'ajax.php',
    data: {
        cachekiller: (new Date()).getTime(),
        action: 'doLogin'
    },
    success: function() {
    // Not being called
    },
    error: function() {
    // Not being called either
    }
});
```

Comment: jQuery ajax accepts "cache: false" parameter for this, there is no need for you to input anything in data object.

Comment: hmm I thought it was a variable of his business

Answer (score 4):

try this:

```
$.ajax({
  url: 'ajax.php',
  cache: false,
  data: {
      action: 'doLogin'
  },
  success: function(data) {
      console.log(data);
  },
  error: function() {
      console.log('error');
  }
});
```

and in ajax.php script:

```
header("Pragma: no-cache");
header("Cache-Control: must-revalidate");
header("Cache-Control: no-cache");
header("Cache-Control: no-store");
header("Expires: 0");
```

Answer (score 1):

OK every thing seems to be fine, here are a few things that you can check out

1. (might seem outrageous)  have you included the jQuery.js
2. make sure that the jQuery.js is included before any other js file
3. put a `/` before the `url` like and  make sure that you have placed the `ajax.php` at the root of your server
4. as mentioned in the comments check for any js errors in the firebug console(firefox) or chrome developer tools

> ```
> $.ajax({
>         url: '/ajax.php',
>         cache:false,
>         data: {
>             action: 'doLogin'
>         },
>         success: function() {
>         // Not being called
>         },
>         error: function() {
>         // Not being called either
>         }
>     });
> ```

you dont need to use cachekiller use `cache:false` prop of ajax method